# Use recursion to find 4 consecutive 1's in 2D array

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

```
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
```

If the above is my input, my code should find four consecutive 1's in it.
I know we have to use a wrap around array to solve this, but I don't know how to implement it.
this is the modified code

```
public static boolean findFourOnes(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(findVertical(arr, i, 0, 0)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(findHorizontal(arr, 0, i, 0)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean findVertical(int[][] arr, int x, int y, int counter){
    //base case
    if(counter == 4)
        return true;

    if(arr[x][y] == 1)//consecutive 
        counter++;
    else//not consecutive
        counter = 0;

   y++;

    // wrap around case
    if(y == arr.length - 1|| y == arr.length +1){
        int max_size=4;
        if(y < 0) {y=x + max_size; return findVertical(arr, x, y, counter);}
        else if(y >= max_size) {y=x % max_size;return findVertical(arr, x, y, counter);}


    }

    return false;
}
public static boolean findHorizontal(int[][] arr, int x, int y, int counter){
    //base case
    if(counter == 4)
        return true;

    if(arr[x][y] == 1)//consecutive 
        counter++;
    else//not consecutive
        counter = 0;

   x++;

    // wrap around case
    if(x == arr.length - 1|| x == arr.length +1){
        int max_size=4;
        if(x < 0) {x=x + max_size;    return findHorizontal(arr, x, y, counter);}
        else if(x >= max_size) {x=x % max_size;    return findHorizontal(arr, x, y, counter);}

    }

   return false;


}
```

This code only checks if there is four consecutive 1's in the array. If it works properly,
my matrix is 4X4. In this code my array `b` is empty with zeros. If I find four 1's I update that matrix.

Comment: Does this mean the 4 consecutive can be horizontal or vertical or diagonal?  You mentioned wrap around, but your example doesn't really make sense.  Are you looking for any 4-group of "1"?

Comment: it can be horizontal and vertical but not diagonal

Comment: This throws `NullPointerException`s a lot, right? Using a `Boolean` of value `null` inside an `if` should do that. Also why are you changing b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 4 parameters.  The 2D array (`arr`), current `x` position, current `y` position, and a int `counter` for 1's.  You should make two separate recursive methods for horizontal searches and vertical searches.  Finally have a primary method that loops the 2D array and calls these two search methods.

Here is the primary method you call and pass in the array:

```
public static boolean findFourOnes(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(findVertical(arr, i, 0, 0)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(findHorizontal(arr, 0, i, 0)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now for the vertical recursive method:

```
public static boolean findVertical(int[][] arr, int x, int y, int counter){
    //base case
    if(counter == 4)
        return true;

    if(arr[x][y] == 1)//consecutive 
        counter++
    else//not consecutive
        counter = 0;

    y++;

    //change this to handle wrap around case
    if(y == arr[x].length - 1)
        return false;

    return findVertical(arr, x, y, counter);
}
```

Now for the horizontal recursive method:

```
public static boolean findHorizontal(int[][] arr, int x, int y, int counter){
    //base case
    if(counter == 4)
        return true;

    if(arr[x][y] == 1)//consecutive 
        counter++
    else//not consecutive
        counter = 0;

    x++;

    //change this to handle wrap around case
    if(x == arr.length - 1)
        return false;

    return findHorizontal(arr, x, y, counter);
}
```

These two recursive methods look very similar, but have notably slight differences.

**NOTE 1:**  I have not tried this code, but it's pretty close to workable (I think...it's pretty late right now...).

**NOTE 2:**  This does not handle wrap around cases, but it should be relatively easy to adapt this pseudo code to work that way.

Comment: appreciate ur help i ll try finish it up and post here for review...thanks

Comment: heyy i did what u said but my code always return false for any output need some help                                           public static boolean findVertical(int[][] arr, int x, int y, int counter) {//base case if (counter == 4) {return true;}if (arr[x][y] == 1) {//consecutive counter++;} else {//not consecutivecounter = 0;}y++;// wrap around caseif (y == arr.length - 1 || y == arr.length + 1) {int max_size = 4;if (y < 0) {y = x + max_size;
 return findVertical(arr, x, y, counter); } else if (y >= max_size) {y = x % max_size;return findVertical(arr, x, y, counter);} } return false;}

Comment: @user3487291 Add the formatted code to the question section so it's easier to read.  Also, give me the sample input you tried with.

Comment: heyy i have modified the question section with the my change in it

Answer (score 2):

A purely recursive variation of CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc's solution:

```
public class FourOnes {

    public static boolean solveArrayRecursively(int[][] array) {
        return solveRowsRecursively(array, 0, 0, 0) || solveColumnsRecursively(array, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static boolean solveColumnsRecursively(int[][] array, int x, int y, int found) {
        if(found >= 4) {
            // We have 4 consecutive ones
            return true;
        }
        if(x != 0 && x >= array.length) {
            // next column
            return solveColumnsRecursively(array, 0, y + 1, 0);
        }
        if(x >= array.length || y >= array[x].length) {
            // no more columns
            return false;
        }
        if(array[x][y] == 1) {
            // found another 1
            return solveColumnsRecursively(array, x + 1, y, found + 1);
        } else {
            // reset count to 0 as there is a gap in the sequence
            return solveColumnsRecursively(array, x + 1, y, 0);
        }
    }

    public static boolean solveRowsRecursively(int[][] array, int x, int y, int found) {
        if(found >= 4) {
            // We have 4 consecutive ones
            return true;
        }
        if(x >= array.length ) {
            // no more rows
            return false;
        }
        if(y >= array[x].length) {
            // next row
            return solveRowsRecursively(array, x + 1, 0, 0);
        }
        if(array[x][y] == 1) {
            // found another 1
            return solveRowsRecursively(array, x, y + 1, found + 1);
        } else {
            // reset count to 0 as there is a gap in the sequence
            return solveRowsRecursively(array, x, y + 1, 0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solveArrayRecursively(new int[][] {
                new int[] {1, 1, 0, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1}
        }));
        System.out.println(solveArrayRecursively(new int[][] {
                new int[] {1, 1, 0, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0},
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1},
                new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1}
        }));
        System.out.println(solveArrayRecursively(new int[][] {
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 1, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 1, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1}
        }));
        System.out.println(solveArrayRecursively(new int[][] {
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1},
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1},
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1},
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1}
        }));
        System.out.println(solveArrayRecursively(new int[0][0]));
    }
}
```

Alternate take:

```
    public static boolean solveArrayRecursively(int[][] array) {
        return solveRecursively(array, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static boolean solveRecursively(int[][] array, int x, int y, int foundX, int foundY) {
        if(foundX >= 4 || foundY >= 4) {
            return true;
        }
        if(x >= array.length || y >= array[x].length) {
            return false;
        }
        if(array[x][y] == 1) {
            return solveRecursively(array, x + 1, y, foundX + 1, 1)
                    || solveRecursively(array, x, y + 1, 1, foundY + 1);
        } else {
            return solveRecursively(array, x + 1, y, 0, 0)
                    || solveRecursively(array, x, y + 1, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Note that while the alternate take will perform better in certain cases it is not a simple [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call], which can increase the risk of stack overflows for large arrays, while the first solution will create more stack overflows in debugging because tail recursions are most probably not optimized.

Also note that the first solution takes `1 + 2*(columns+1)*(rows+1)` calls at a maximum recursion-depth of `1 + (columns+1)*(rows+1)` where as the second takes calls at a maximum depth of `1 + columns + rows` like this:

```
   x=0 x=1 x=2 x=3 x=4
y=0 1   1   1   1   1
y=1 1   2   3   4   4
y=2 1   3   6   10  10
y=3 1   4   10  20  20
y=4 1   4   10  20
```

Comment: thank you for your help....i jst want to let u knw tht i hve to use wrap up array

Comment: hey i m trying to change the  code of purely recursive variation of CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc so tht it can work for the wrap around array but it is always returning false

Comment: @user3487291 where doe you need rto wrap arround? Are lines connected? Are columns connected? Are just 4 ones anywhere enough?

Comment: i m developing kmap which need to check the corner for 1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write separate methods for rows and columns - just transpose the input array and use the same method:

```
public class FourConsecutiveOnes {

    public static boolean fourOnes(final int[][] input, int x, int y, int remaining) {
        if (remaining == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (y == input[0].length) {
            remaining = 4;
            y = 0;
            x = x + 1;
        }
        if (x == input.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (input[x][y] == 1) {
            return fourOnes(input, x, y + 1, remaining - 1);
        } else {
            return fourOnes(input, x, y + 1, 4);
        }
    }

    public static int[][] transpose(final int[][] input) {
        int[][] result = new int[input[0].length][input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < input[0].length; j++) {
                result[j][i] = input[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][] input = new int[][]{
                new int[] {1, 1, 0, 0},
                new int[] {1, 1, 1, 0},
                new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0},
                new int[] {1, 0, 0, 0},
        };

        System.out.println(fourOnes(input, 0, 0, 4) || fourOnes(transpose(input), 0, 0, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your transpose is iteratively. Why not go `public static boolean solveArrayIteratively(int[][] array) {
    final int[] yCounts = new int[array[0].length];
    int xCount;
    for (int[] row : array) {
        xCount = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
            if (row[y] == 1) {
                yCounts[y]++;
                xCount++;
                if (yCounts[y] >= 4 || xCount >= 4) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                yCounts[y] = 0;
                xCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}`